# Initialize many readonly fields without a constructor

Tags: c#, serialization, syntax, access-modifiers

I have a Serializable class that contains data stored in fields.
That class is instantiated, serialized and sent to the Client Program.

Important: The class is in a 3rd Assembly along with other Serializables.

Example Class (3rd Assembly):

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class Settings
{
    public int A;
    public bool B;
    …
    public object N;
}
```

Example Object Initializer (Server):

```
var s = new Settings
{
    A = 0;
    B = true;
    …
    N = new Object();
};
```

The Client Program Deserializes and uses the Object.

An issue is that I don't want to allow the Client Program to change the values of the fields.
This is not for security reasons, (they could even use Reflection...), but to reduce chances of failure.

But the real problem is, there are TOO MANY fields, I don't want to make a 30+ parameter constructor so I can use readonly fields. Also, an Object Initializer wouldn't work.

The first thought was to use public properties with restricted setters, so I could still (maybe) use an object Initializer.
But, since the class is on a 3rd assembly, I cant use internal setters.
Protected is useless for this, because I would have to basically rewrite the base class (even made it sealed now).

Now I'm thinking to have a constructor that takes an `IDictionary<string, dynamic>` or an `IDictionary<string, object>` and initialize readonly fields, but this would be prone to errors if any field was to be added or removed in the future.

I ran out of ideas, and its seems to me that I will have to make something as ugly as:

```
public Settings
(
    int a,
    bool b,
    …,
    object n
)
{
    A = a;
    B = b;
    …
    N = n;
}
```

I suppose I could use Reflection to set the readonly fields...

Is there any more Elegant way of accomplishing this?
Thanks!

Comment: If you have this problem, there's a good change your class is far too complicated and not following the single responsibility principle.

Comment: @DavidG I would normally say so, but it has only one responsibility.
Send Runtime Settings over to the Client.

Comment: If it were me, I'd use public properties with private setters.  However, that will require that you do all your serialization work by hand (I believe).

Comment: @Flydog57 And I would still have to use a constructor to initialize them.

Comment: No, you can say `public int A {get; private set;} = 25;`  That initialization code gets prefixed to every constructor of your class.

Comment: @Flydog57 Sorry, I didn't explain this very clearly, this class doesn't know the values for the fields (at compile time), its only purpose is to serve as a data-structure to hold the values. The class that creates the instance is the one that puts together the values (from Runtime Info and DataBase).

Comment: If you don't set them at compile time, then don't _have to use a constructor to initialize them_.  If you don't know the values at compile time, you can't initialize them in a constructor anyway; let the framework initialize things to default values.  Consider looking into "Mappers" (similar to AutoMapper or the Mapper that Dapper uses).  It's pretty easy to write one yourself (using Reflection) if you are OK with the cost of `Invoking` two `MethodInfos` (one to read a property from the source and the other to set the property on the destination.

Comment: @ Flydog57 Thanks, I will have a look at Mappers, and I do think that some Reflection-based solution would be the most sane.

Comment: Could you break your class down in to smaller classes?

Comment: The constructor, clumsy as it is, is the usual solution to this problem.

Comment: @ Andrew I though of that, I can do it, but I would have to either then put them all in another wrapper class, or send several 'packets' to the client with each Serialized object...

Comment: @mjwills Yeah, I'm afraid it is. I think I will just do that.